# How to Toggle Multiple Hide/Display state

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble coming up with a method that allows me to toggle multiple displays on and off without hard-coding a function for each displayed component.
I was wondering if there is a way to toggle these display states with one function kind of like and onChange event.

```
    this.state = {
        showOne: false,
        showTwo: false
    }


display = () => {
let { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: !value })
}

return(
<button name={showOne} value={this.state.showOne} onClick={this.display}>
{!showOne
? (
null
) : (
<div><ComponentOne/></div>
)}

</button
<button name={showtwo} value={this.state.showTwo} onClick={this.display}>
</button
{!showTwo
? (
null
) : (
<div><ComponentTwo/></div>
)}
```

this only somewhat works the issue is that it changes the state to a string instead of a Boolean. aka showOne: false => showOne: 'false'.
I know the name and value properties are for inputs but I was wondering if there was something similar along these lines so I can have one function that allows the displaying/un-displaying of multiple components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set them up with an inline function that passes in an identifier, which is then used as a key in the state:

```
onClick={() => toggle(itemName)}
```

```
toggle = (itemName) => {
  this.setState({ [itemName]: !this.state[itemName] });
}
```

Another option is to define a component for the button that takes `name` and `onClick` props, and have the component’s internal onClick invoke the prop onClick with the name. (It’s hard to write example code from the phone. I can update this if it isn’t clear.)

Answer (score 0):

```
   toggleDisplay = (name) => {
    this.setState({ 
        [name]: !this.state[name]
    })
}

onClick={()=> this.toggleDisplay('showOne')}
```

Worked Tyvm